# Exposing namespace from an assembly in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# project which has a namespace A. The output of the project is a library(dll). When I try to add a reference to this dll file from another project, I am not able to see the namespace A present in the dll. Is there anything that I should do while creating the dll file so as to see the namespace? Please help me in this regard at the earliest.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: please provide some code samples so we can get a better idea of what you have in your library project. Just a namespace is not going to cut it. In order to be able to see types you've defined in assembly A, these types need to be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are:

- Adding a reference to the DLL in the consuming projects references setting.
- Made your classes public.
- Including a using statement at the top of your file, or referencing the full namespace to the type that your dependent project is consuming.

Project References:

[image: Project References]

Comment: yes, I am adding the reference to the DLL in the consuming project.

Comment: You have the using clause then?

Comment: I had to make some classes public. Thanks Ritch Melton.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version of the .Net framework targeted by your dll matches that of the program you are trying to reference it from. For example, if you have an assembly which targets the 4.0 framework and you try to reference it from a project which is targeting an older version of the framework you can run into these weird problems where you can't find the types in the assembly.